# boot issue after turning off graphical desktop

Tags: boot, gui

I am a beginner with Linux looking for some help with a problem I've run into.

After I power up my system, I get this message for a brief second:

/dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 219225/1875698 files, 2696195/7503360 blocks

[   6.303241] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

[   8.999430] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f

However, right after, my GUI starts up just fine.
I am trying to run it without the graphical desktop, so I type:
sudo systemctl stop gdm
in the terminal. It prompts me for my password, and then restarts. After restarting, this comes up on the screen:

/dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 219225/1875698 files, 2696195/7503360 blocks

[   8.011173] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

[  12.681856] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

[  13.160110] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)

and I am unable to do anything else.

I am learning basic commands to explore the directory, and was previously able to, but no longer can. When I restart my computer from this screen, it goes back to loading the graphical desktop. Here is my pastebin from Boot Repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7NRYXJXmRr/ Should I go forward with their suggested repair? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, you don't need any such repair when the system boots and that even irrespective of the desktop environment opening or not. Now, why exactly do you think you need to run the OS without the DE? You know you have a Terminal, don't you?

Comment: I'm taking a free Introduction to Linux class on edx.org. Following their directions, they wanted me to stop gdm and run without GUI to try out some basic commands. So I'm simply doing what they're teaching me to do.. But you're right,  I suppose I could just run everything in the terminal, anyways! ;) I suppose me knowing I didn't have this problem just a couple days ago, but now do, is making me wonder if I did something to cause this and how I can fix it. :)